# Excel get sorted data from a ListObject without sorting it

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I'm trying to get sorted/filtered data from an Excel ListObject into an array I can work with.
Because of the reason below, i'm looking for alternatives to ADO query.
I found LO.DataBodyRange.Sort (see code at the end), but i'm not sure how I can use it to retrieve the data sorted into an array withouth modifying the table (which is super important because sorting a listObject causes named ranges inside the table to lose their correct refersTo).

If you have any experience with this please let me know how I could do that.

Reason:

I am currently using an ADO query to get the data sorted and filtered, but there are 2 reasons why i'm looking for alternatives:

1. It is highly dependent on "Dynamic Data Exchange Server Lookup" setting in Excel, setting that was reset to unchecked with last Excel update and this caused the query to crash on objRecordset.open.

```
objRecordset.Open strSQL, _
        objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

2. Also after the latest Excel update, the query went from a 1s runtime to 3-5 seconds, and for repeated actions that would be bad.

```
Sub getTableData()
    
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim dResult As New Scripting.Dictionary, dKey As Variant, arrItem() As Variant, arrI As ListRow, I As Long
    Dim arrDataBodyRange()
    
    Set LO = wsInputsDb.ListObjects("tblInputs")
    
    dKey = "headers"
    arrItem = LO.HeaderRowRange.Value
    
    dResult.Add dKey, arrItem
    
    arrDataBodyRange = LO.DataBodyRange.Value
    'arrDataBodyRange = LO.DataBodyRange.Sort("SubSection order").Value
    
'    I = 0
'    For Each arrI In LO.ListRows
'        I = I + 1
'        dResult.Add I, arrI.Range.Value
'    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the worksheet function `SORT`. You have to provide the column index by which the listobject should be sorted.

```vb
With lo
    arrData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort( _
        .DataBodyRange, .ListColumns("Subsection order").Index, 1 _
        )
End With
```

I think you need Excel 365 for this.

Update: double sorting

````
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    arrData = .Sort(.Sort(lo.DataBodyRange, lo.ListColumns("subsection order").Index, 1), _
        lo.ListColumns("second column").Index, 1)
End With
```
````

Comment: This is such and awsome solution. The thing is I can't find any documentation on this function used this way and VBA does not tell you what each variable is. is the 1 Asc? Can you sort by multiplce columns?

Comment: The parameters are the same as for the formula on the worksheet. No, you can only sort by one column - but you can do double sort ... i will enhance the answer